# How to set height and width of button inside a Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a button of fixed width and height inside a container. But, for some reason button takes height and width of Container. I tried using `SizedBox` and `ButtonTheme` but they don't work as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      // home: EditorScreen(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: 65,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 50,
                height: 50,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("Test"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `ButtonTheme` is not necessary.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints - read the first 3 paragraphs

Comment: your welcome - i said 3 paragraphs, but to be honest check all 29 examples they provide

Comment: I ended up checking the whole article lol.

Comment: *"I ended up checking the whole article"* - good for you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify for parent container `alignment` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding **padding**  to the container

Answer (score 0):

If you add the button center of the container then wrap with `Center` widget or if you want some other alignment then please specify that using `alignment` property.